# Why did Geralt of Rivia refuse this?

Tags: the-witcher

Spoilers for the Witcher 3 ahead:

> Geralt came to Emperor Emhyr var Emreis, Deithwen Addan yn Carn aep Morvudd, requesting aid for the Battle of Kaer Morhen. Emhyr agreed but Geralt refused when he heard that Morvran Voorhis was leading the troops.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kaer Morhen is in Kaedwen, which is now part of Redania, which is at war with Nilfgaard. Emhyr’s forces under Nilfgaardian command would never have withdrawn from a strongly fortified position in enemy territory after the Wild Hunt had been defeated. The witchers would have lost control of Kaer Morhen, and Redania would have suffered a serious military setback.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what does this have to do with Voorhis specifically? If the issue/concern is with Nilfgaard itself, why even bother going to ask Emhyr for assistance if there is the intention of refusing because "Nilfgaard bad"?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb The issue isn’t with Voorhis specifically — any other Nilfgaardian general would be as bad. The issue is with whether the troops are commanded by a Nilfgaardian or by Geralt.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that clears it up. It's been a while since I played through the game completely, but that makes sense as far as what I remember.